# Visual Studio Code's Java Compiler Not Showing Certain Compile Errors

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

When running Java code, I have noticed that certain compile time errors will not be displayed.

[image]

Here at `ar[2]=10;` it is not showing error at compile time.

But it should show compile error like this, as you can see the red juggle line at `ar[2]=10`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The white dot on the right of the file name indicates that the current file has not been saved.

[image]

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save the file, or add the following settings to achieve real-time saving.

```
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
```

In addition, your code `ar[1]="HM"` also lacks a semicolon.

[image]

Make sure you have the full [***Extension Pack for Java***](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack) installed